# High cpu temperature until i open task manager then it drops down to normal

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-temperature

i have problem.with cpu temps it started yesterday when intalled some shady program and nothing happend when i clicked that exe file, i think in background it did something,
When i leave pc on idle temps go from below 40 to high 70s 76 78 ... and if i open task manager it drops fo below 40 again, if i leave TM opened nothing happens, temps are normal untill i close it.  Windows antivirus doesn't picking it up, a tried some cmd solutions like scf scan, restore health, didn't helped,  i need a way to find this malware without reinstalling windows,  if u had one like this please share solution.. thanks

Cpu i5 13600k
Mb, gygabyte z790 ddr5
Ram corsair vengeance 32 gb

Comment: Run Full Windows Defender Online and Offline scans.